# Symfony2 & JMSSecurityExtraBundle: "not allowed is forbidden"

Tags: php, symfony

I am trying to achieve "what not allowed is forbidden" strategy, and at the same time to keep flexibility of FOSRest annotation. Without discussing the necesserity of this usecase - can I deny all, and allow for anonymouse users access only some methods, via annotation like

```
use JMS\SecurityExtraBundle\Annotation\Secure;
use FOS\RestBundle\Controller\Annotations\Get;

....
/**
* @Secure(roles="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY")
* @Get('/testpage')
**/
```

and deny all (except login, of course, using ACL)

```
    - { path: ^/login,                    roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/login_check,              roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/,                         roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY }
```

At first I really hoped for

```
secure_all_services: true
```

notation of jmssecurity config, but it only enables whole-project parsing of jms annotations.

My sample isn't working, I am sure that JMSSecurity itself is working OK, without ACL deny rule I can deny single element by annotation.

Answer (score 0):

if i remember correctly the annotation syntax is

```
/**
 * @Secure(roles="ROLE_ADMIN")
 **/
```

this will only work on methods. For classes you need the `@PreAuthorize` annotation

see http://jmsyst.com/bundles/JMSSecurityExtraBundle/master/annotations

Comment: You are right, but that's not the point. I've tried to do it with right syntax, just mistype. I am still couldn't disable everything and allow methods from annotation.